# How to develop, compile, deploy HDFS source code quickly so that I could debug?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I use remote debug HDFS source code in Eclipse, but it is so inconvenient that I have to deploy the jars every time I modified the source code.
Is there any way to develop, compile, deploy HDFS source code quickly?
I need all your help!!! THX!

Answer (score 0):

Though it's made by myself, I usually use [docker-hadoop-cluster](https://github.com/Lewuathe/docker-hadoop-cluster) for my development.

The only requirement is Docker. This framework deploy your HDFS code to multiple node HDFS cluster on your laptop. In addition to HDFS, it launched YARN cluster.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Lewuathe/docker-hadoop-cluster.git
$ cd docker-hadoop-cluster
# Copy your self build Hadoop source code
$ cp /path/to/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz hadoop-base
$ make
$ make run
```

If you have any problem, please let me know on [issue](https://github.com/Lewuathe/docker-hadoop-cluster/issues).

Thanks

Comment: I only need to modify the HDFS source code, I don't compile all the Hadoop .